# inverse of asymptotic Toeplitz matrix with band limited associated function

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, toeplitz-operators

I am reviewing a controversial paper, and the main result, a revolution within my field, comes down to whether or not the following is true. I strongly believe it is not, but would need  confirmation.

Let $X_n$ be an $n \times n$ Toeplitz matrix with associated function $f(\omega)$ where $f(\omega)$ is band limited, i.e., $f(\omega)=0$ for $|\omega|>\beta \pi$, for some $\beta < 1$. Thus, element  (k,l) in $X_n$ is
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\omega)\exp(-(k-l)i \omega)d\omega$$.

Is $X_n$ invertible as $n\to \infty$ ?

For any finite $n$ it is, but to me it seems as Szegö's theorem, which gives the asymptotic eigenvalue distribution, will kick so the the inverse does not exist as $n \to \infty $.&=

Using a particular construction, which requires $X_n$ to be invertible, the authors can prove some remarkable things, as $n\to \infty$. I believe that the mistake is exactly that they assume that $X_n$ is invertible as $n\to \infty$….

Comment: Is your situation finitely many bands? I don't understand your notation..

Comment: Could you define the "associated function" to a Toplitz matrix ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why $X_n$ would be invertible (as you claim it is) for *general* $f$. Is your question about a specific $f$ then?

Comment: $X_n$ (finite n) is perhaps not invertible in general, but for the particular $f(\omega)$ that the authors deal with, it is. You may for example assume that $f(\omega)=1,\, |\omega|<\beta \pi$ and 0 otherwise.